# Sniffing communications not working

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, sniffing, network-monitoring

I am looking for a VirtualBox guru. I tried several settings without success and I don't know what should I try further.

I have three virtual machines:

- Two Windows 7 machines (master-slave simulator)
- One CentOS 7 machine (with sniffer - Suricata IDS)

I have no problem setting up connections between the VMs, but it is impossible to sniff Windows communications on the CentOS VM. CentOS only sees broadcast packets.

I tried connecting them with Internal network, Host-only Adapter and NAT networks. Promiscuous mode was set as "Allow All" in all cases.

Sniffing works when bridge mode is used, but that is not what I need.

Thanks for any advice.

VB version: Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 5.2.18_Ubuntu

Host: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Just a thought, but you might wish to try connecting them through a fourth machine acting as a virtual router and try sniffing that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I already solved this problem with two different internal networks. There is solution in a few points:

- 1.network 192.168.100.0/24 between win1 (192.168.100.1) and centos (192.168.100.200)
- 2.network 192.168.200.0/24 between centos (192.168.200.200) and win2 (192.168.200.1)
- on the win1 set up routing to second subnet through centos - `route -p ADD 192.168.200.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.200` (run as admin in command line)
- on the win2 set up routing to first subnet through centos - `route -p ADD 192.168.100.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.200.200`

Vioala. Thats it.